# Getting object store already exists inside onupgradeneeded

Tags: javascript, indexeddb

My code is as follows (usually naming convention for the well-known objects):

```
var DBOpenRequest = window.indexedDB.open("messages", 6);
//...
DBOpenRequest.onupgradeneeded = function(event) { 
  console.log("Need to upgrade.");
  var db = event.target.result;
  console.log(db);

  db.onerror = function(event) {
     console.log("Error upgrading.");
  };

  // Create an objectStore for this database
  var objectStore = db.createObjectStore("messages", { keyPath: "id", autoIncrement: true });
    };
```

This ran fine for versions 3 and 4. When it came to version 5, I get the error:

> Failed to execute 'createObjectStore' on 'IDBDatabase': An object store with the specified name already exists.
>       at IDBOpenDBRequest.DBOpenRequest.onupgradeneeded

Isn't the `createObjectStore` operating on a new version of the database which is empty? How do I fix the error?

I happened to log the `db` object and the details are below:

[image]

I am curious why the version number is different in the summary line and when expanded.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

> Isn't the createObjectStore operating on a new version of the database which is empty?

When you get `upgradeneeded` the database is in whatever state you left it in before. Since you don't know what versions of your code a user will have visited, you need to look at the event's `oldVersion` to find out what that was. The typical pattern is something like this:

```
var rq = indexedDB.open('db', 5);
rq.onupgradeneeded = function(e) {
  var db = rq.result;
  if (e.oldVersion < 1) {
    // do initial schema creation
    db.createObjectStore('users');
  }
  if (e.oldVersion < 2) {
    // do 1->2 upgrade
    var s = db.createObjectStore('better_users');
    s.createIndex('some_index', ...);
    db.deleteObjectStore('users'); // migrating data would be better
  }
  if (e.oldVersion < 3) {
    // do 2->3 upgrade
    rq.transaction.objectStore('better_users').createIndex('index2', ...);
  }
  if (e.oldVersion < 4) {
    // do 3->4 upgrade
    db.createObjectStore('messages', ...);
  }
  if (e.oldVersion < 5) {
    // do 4->5 upgrade
    // ...
  }
}
```

> I am curious why the version number is different in the summary line and when expanded.

That one is subtle... I believe at the point where the `5` was logged the database had started the upgrade. But [because an exception was thrown in the `upgradeneeded` handler the upgrade was aborted](https://w3c.github.io/IndexedDB/#upgrade-transaction-steps), and [the version number was rolled back](https://w3c.github.io/IndexedDB/#abort-an-upgrade-transaction) to `4` before the details were logged.

Comment: I see, so the database is not empty if the browser had already opened a previous version.

Comment: what is `rq.tx`? It's `undefined` for me.

Comment: Whoops, should be `rq.transaction` - I'll fix

Answer (score 7):

The best way to upgrade the DB is checking if the store name is already there. In this example I'm using https://npmjs.com/idb

```
openDB('db-name', version, {
  upgrade(db, oldVersion, newVersion, transaction) {
    if(!db.objectStoreNames.contains('messages')) {
      db.createObjectStore('messages', { keyPath: "id", autoIncrement: true })
    }
  }
})
```

If you need to check if an indexName already exist, you can get the objectStore and check for the indexNames property if it contains the indexName you need.

```
openDB('db-name', version, {
  upgrade(db, oldVersion, newVersion, transaction) {
    const storeName = transaction.objectStore('storeName')
    if(!storeName.indexNames.contains('indexName')) {
        storeName.createIndex('indexName', 'propertyName', { unique: false });
    }
  }
})
```

Using indexDB API with indexNames and objectStoreNames to check if something is either there or not makes my code way more reliable and easy to maintain, it is also briefly mentioned on [Working with IndexDB Using database versioning](https://web.dev/indexeddb/#creating-object-stores)